# Knime for Retail prediction models

Tags: knime

I am quite new to the data science field, and I was wondering if it is worth the effort to deep dive into Knime which looks quite powerful for many data science uses.

I know python and scikit-learn but it seems very efficient that I can do most of my data science projects (business related) with a simple GUI interface and achieve similar if not better results than coding.

The specific ways I will use Knime or the other:
- Advising retail firms about association rules
- Customer segmentation
- Analyzing retail data to find patters in customer behavior

Thank you, Dan